# How can I set reference in rms R package

Tags: r, spline, cox-regression

I'm trying to plot 'restricted cubic spline' as image below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrCUV.png)
I did my best, and I write a R code as below

```
dd <- datadist(dta)
options(datadist='dd')

dd$limits$癤풹ge[2]

model <- cph(Surv(time, death) ~ trial + rcs(癤풹ge, 4) + smoking + sex + stage, data=dta, surv=T)
ggplot(Predict(model, 癤풹ge, trial))
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to set reference in this code.
As you could see in the picture above, researcher set reference on 80.
Please help me how to set reference.
Also, if there is a problem in code, please tell me too.

Comment: [What is the reference point for a Cox proportionall hazard spline model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204346/what-is-the-reference-point-for-a-cox-proprtional-hazard-spline-model)

Comment: It's not specific. Let me suppose it is 50. Could you help me?? (T_T)